# Adding selection data from one layer to new field in another layer using QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, fields-attributes, overlapping-features

[image: Screenshot added]

I have two polygon layers:

A) Contains around 500 river catchment areas

B) Contains 100 river catchment areas

I want to create a new data field in *Catchment A* showing which catchment (*Catchment B*) the catchment (*Catchment A*) belongs to.

I could do this manually by "Selection by location", but since there are a lot of rows, it would be nice to do this in the Field Calculator.

QGIS-version is 3.24.3 and I use the following expression:

overlay_intersects('Catchment B',"id",sort_by_intersection_size:='des')[0]

As you can see on the screendump, catchment 200 (Layer B) overlaps with catchment 3110,7330, 7320 and 7310 from Layer A. I want "200" added to a new field in the table of these fore catchments.

Comment: Try this [`array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Layer B', "id"),',')`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function. The basic expression is:

```
overlay_intersects('LayerB', "id")[0]
```

**Explanation**: for each feature of `LayerA`, get the value of field `"id"` from `LayerB` of those features that intersect with the current feature. The result is an array of `id` values. With `[0]` you get the first element (array index, starting with 0 for first element).

**Variant**: If some of the features of `LayerA` intersect more than one feature of `LayerB`, you can get the largest overlapping area with this expression (argument `sort_by_intersection_size` only available in newer QGIS versions):

```
overlay_intersects('LayerB',"id",sort_by_intersection_size:='des')[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to run the suggested line, replacing layer name and id, but unfortunately it only gives me a column of null values.

Comment: What QGIS version do you use? Can you post one or more screenshots showing your layers panel and the expression used? You can edit the initial question, post the screenshots there, copy the links to the images and insert the linkes here in the comments, deleting the images from the edited questions (or simply don't save the changes).

Comment: I've updated my original post and added a screenshot and a bit of explanation. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you have an attribute field called `id` on `Catchment B` layer? If not, it can't work. If so, it should work. Otherwise: can you share your project + data (layers) for testing?

Comment: Just tried again and it worked! Think I might messed up something in the expression, but now it works. Thank you again - and thank you too @Taras.